# Casting an inherited class back to the base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, memory, casting

What happens to the data stored in the fields of a child class if and instance of that child class is cast back to the inherited class? And how does this work in memory?

```
public abstract class AchievementNode : PrioritizedData
{
public enum NodeTypes
{
    NONE   = 0x0,
    HEAD   = 0x1,
    TAIL   = 0x2,
    TYPE   = 0x4,
    DATA   = 0x8,
    LEVEL  = 0x16,
    GLOBAL = 0x32
}

public NodeTypes nodeType;

public virtual AchievementNode Init(NodeTypes type, params int[] enumData)
{
    nodeType = type;
    return this;
}
}

public class AchievementTypeNode : AchievementNode
{
public enum AchievementTypes {TIME,COMPLETION,UNLOCK,SOCIAL,ACTION};


public AchievementTypes AchievementType; 


public override AchievementNode Init(AchievementNode.NodeTypes type)
{
    base.Init(type);

    return (AchievementNode)this;
}
}
```

Comment: Set up a few tests and see

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting is simply changing how you're referencing the object.  It does not change the object itself.

Nothing happens to the data in the child class when the object is cast.  The only difference is that you can only refer to the object as an instance of the base class, but the actual data is that of the child class.

If you refer to your red car as only 'car', is it any less red?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens to the data - it just isn't visible to the consumer of the object that has been cast to the base type.

Casting a derived type to a base type doesn't mean a new object is created, it simply changes the compile time type checking and can influence any code you have that does run time type checking or manipulation.